# Parsing JSON to JSON in Liquid Template using for loop. How to iterate through lists in JSON using Liquid Template?

Tags: json, parsing, azure-logic-apps, dotliquid, liquid-template

[image: I have this json that i am trying to parse into another json using liquid template. I don't know how to loop through elements.]

```
{
"SAP": [
    {% for Record in content %}{
        {% assign res = Record.d['results'] %}      
            "SSO ID": "{{ res[0].username }}"   
    },
    {% endfor %}
    ]
}
```

Using this - i am only able to get username field of the first element from both results but not the second element. I want to be able to iterate through all the elements both results and get their values..

PLEASE HELP!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For our requirement, I initialize a variable named "data" and store the below value to simulate your situation.

```
{
    "content": [
        {
            "d": {
                "results": [
                    {
                        "username": "hury11",
                        "email": "test@mail.com"
                    },
                    {
                        "username": "hury22",
                        "email": "test@mail.com"
                    },
                    {
                        "username": "hury33",
                        "email": "test@mail.com"
                    }
                ],
                "_count": "17425",
                "_next": ""
            }
        },
        {
            "d": {
                "results": [
                    {
                        "username": "hury44",
                        "email": "test@mail.com"
                    },
                    {
                        "username": "hury55",
                        "email": "test@mail.com"
                    },
                    {
                        "username": "hury66",
                        "email": "test@mail.com"
                    }
                ],
                "_count": "17425",
                "_next": ""
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

[image]

Then parse json and use "Transform JSON to JSON" action.
[image]

My liquid template shown as below:

```
{
    "SAP": [
        {% for Record in content %}
           [
           {% for result in Record.d.results %}
              {
                "SSO ID": "{{result.username}}",
                "email": "{{result.email}}"
              },
           {% endfor %}
           ],
        {% endfor %}
    ]
}
```

If you want the `d` map in your result json data, the liquid template should be as below:

```
{
    "SAP": [
        {% for Record in content %}
        {"d":
           [
           {% for result in Record.d.results %}
              {
                "SSO ID": "{{result.username}}",
                "email": "{{result.email}}"
              },
           {% endfor %}
           ]
        },
        {% endfor %}
    ]
}
```

Hope it helps~